# Changing VBA code - into - SQL statement

Tags: sql, vba, syntax

I have this code in Excel VBA:

```vb
If Cells(lngRow, ConstTASTMS_ActivateTime).Value < getdate() - 7 Then

  Cells(lngRow, ConstTASTimeClass).Value = "BOH"

  If Cells(lngRow, ConstTASTask_Status) = "Closed" Then

    If Cells(lngRow, ConstTASActual_EndDate).Value <= getdate() - 7 Then

      Cells(lngRow, ConstTASTimeClass).Value = "BOH-CO"

    Else

      Cells(lngRow, ConstTASTimeClass).Value = "BOH-C"

    End If
  End If

  If Cells(lngRow, ConstTASTask_StatusReason) = "Canceled" Then

    If Cells(lngRow, ConstTASActual_EndDate).Value <= getdate() Then

      Cells(lngRow, ConstTASTimeClass).Value = "BOH-XO"

    Else

      Cells(lngRow, ConstTASTimeClass).Value = "BOH-X"

    End If

  End If

Else

  Cells(lngRow, ConstTASTimeClass).Value = "New"

  If Cells(lngRow, ConstTASTask_Status) = "Closed" Then Cells(lngRow, ConstTASTimeClass).Value = "New-C"

  If Cells(lngRow, ConstTASTask_Status) = "Canceled" Then Cells(lngRow, ConstTASTimeClass).Value = "New-X"

End If
```

And now, I need to translate it into the SQL statement.
So far, I got this, and don't think it's correct.
Can someone please take a look and help me to correct it?

```sql
  CASE WHEN TMS_ActivateTime < getdate() - 7 THEN

  TimeClass = "BOH"

  CASE WHEN Task_Status = "Closed" THEN

  CASE WHEN Actual_EndDate  <= getdate() - 7 THEN

  TimeClass  = "BOH-CO"

ELSE

  TimeClass  = "BOH-C"

  CASE WHEN  Task_StatusReason = "Canceled" THEN

  CASE WHEN  Actual_EndDate  <= getdate() THEN

  TimeClass  = "BOH-XO"

    ELSE

  TimeClass  = "BOH-X"

ELSE

  TimeClass  = "New"

  CASE WHEN  Task_Status = "Closed" THEN  TimeClass  = "New-C"

  CASE WHEN  Task_Status = "Canceled" THEN  TimeClass  = "New-X"

END
```

Comment: Please read [*Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1188513), and [ask]. Your question is missing a, well, question.

Comment: remember case is case when condition then value else othervalue end.  I don't see a single end to your multiple cases here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give it a shot. As the CASE will not evaluate any further after a WHEN is true, we need to sometimes reverse the order in which the values are assigned to TimeClass.

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN TMS_ActivateTime < getdate() - 7 THEN
  CASE WHEN Task_StatusReason = "Canceled" THEN
    CASE WHEN  Actual_EndDate  <= getdate() THEN
    'BOH-XO'
    ELSE 'BOH-X'
    END
  WHEN Task_Status = 'Closed' THEN
    CASE WHEN Actual_EndDate  <= getdate() - 7 THEN
    'BOH-CO'
    ELSE 'BOH-C'
    END
  ELSE 'BOH'
  END
ELSE
  CASE 
  WHEN TaskStatus = 'Canceled' THEN 'New-X' 
  WHEN TaskStatus = 'Closed' THEN 'New-C'
  ELSE 'New' END 
END
AS TimeClass
```

Answer (score 0):

While it is not necessary in SQL syntax, it is helpful to format your case statements to see where a field ends and begins, i.e.:

```
--Field 1
CASE
    WHEN
    THEN
    ELSE
END
--Field 2
CASE
   WHEN
   THEN
       CASE
       --still Field 2
           WHEN
           THEN
       END
END
```